# Parameter value did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]

Tags: java, mysql, spring, web, many-to-many

I have specific problem- I'm writing web application in Spring framework (Java). I try to add objects to another object (as list element)- many to many, but I have exception. Below I attach specific elements of code: Class Coffee; Class Orders; vaadin UI fragment, where I add elements from Grid.
**Exception:**

```
2021-12-03 20:17:08.368 ERROR 8156 --- [nio-8081-exec-9] c.v.flow.server.DefaultErrorHandler      : 

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [Coffee{coffeeID=1, name='Kawa 1', type='Ziarnista', originCountry='Arabika', intensity=3, weight=12.0, price=45.0, stockAmount=300, description='xddddddddddddddddddd'}] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [Coffee{coffeeID=1, name='Kawa 1', type='Ziarnista', originCountry='Arabika', intensity=3, weight=12.0, price=45.0, stockAmount=300, description='xddddddddddddddddddd'}] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:374) ~[spring-orm-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:235) ~[spring-orm-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551) ~[spring-orm-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy109.updateOrders(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at pl.project.pss.service.OrdersService.updateOrder(OrdersService.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
    at pl.project.pss.view.coffees_page.CoffeesPage.lambda$init$9b1b5227$3(CoffeesPage.java:140) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.fireEventForListener(ComponentEventBus.java:205) ~[flow-server-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.handleDomEvent(ComponentEventBus.java:373) ~[flow-server-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.lambda$addDomTrigger$dd1b7957$1(ComponentEventBus.java:264) ~[flow-server-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.lambda$fireEvent$2(ElementListenerMap.java:443) ~[flow-server-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.fireEvent(ElementListenerMap.java:443) ~[flow-server-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.EventRpcHandler.handleNode(EventRpcHandler.java:61) ~[flow-server-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.handle(AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.java:66) ~[flow-server-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocationData(ServerRpcHandler.java:412) ~[flow-server-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.lambda$handleInvocations$1(ServerRpcHandler.java:393) ~[flow-server-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:393) ~[flow-server-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:320) ~[flow-server-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:92) ~[flow-server-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40) ~[flow-server-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1559) ~[flow-server-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:252) ~[flow-server-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:111) ~[vaadin-spring-12.4.0.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:353) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [Coffee{coffeeID=1, name='Kawa 1', type='Ziarnista', originCountry='Arabika', intensity=3, weight=12.0, price=45.0, stockAmount=300, description='xddddddddddddddddddd'}] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:27) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.validate(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.setBindValue(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.expandListValuedParameters(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:656) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doExecuteUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1700) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1683) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ModifyingExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:239) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 77 common frames omitted
```

**Coffee.java:**

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Coffee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_coffee")
    private Integer coffeeID;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    @Column(name="origin_country")
    private String originCountry;
    private Integer intensity;
    private Float weight;
    private Float price;
    @Column(name="stock_amount")
    private Integer stockAmount;
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "order_coffee",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_coffee"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_order"))
    private List<Orders> orders;


    public Coffee(String name, String type, String originCountry, Integer intensity, Float weight, Float price,
                  Integer stockAmount, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.originCountry = originCountry;
        this.intensity = intensity;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.price = price;
        this.stockAmount = stockAmount;
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Coffee{" +
                "coffeeID=" + coffeeID +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", type='" + type + '\'' +
                ", originCountry='" + originCountry + '\'' +
                ", intensity=" + intensity +
                ", weight=" + weight +
                ", price=" + price +
                ", stockAmount=" + stockAmount +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Orders.java:**

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Orders {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_orders")
    private Integer ordersID;
    @Column(name="orders_status")
    private OrderStatus ordersStatus;
    @Column(name = "ordering_date_time")
    private LocalDateTime orderingDateTime;
    @Column(name = "is_reminder_sent")
    private boolean isReminderSent;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private User orderingUser;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "orders", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Coffee> coffees_in_orders;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_rate", referencedColumnName = "id_rate")
    private Rate orders_rate;

    public Orders(User orderingUser, List<Coffee> coffees_in_orders) {
        this.ordersStatus = STATUS_BASKET;
        this.orderingDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.isReminderSent = false;
        this.orderingUser = orderingUser;
        this.coffees_in_orders = coffees_in_orders;
    }
}
```

fragment of **CoffeesPage.java:**

```
popUpWindowConfirmButton.addClickListener(l->{
            if(loggedUser!=null){
                if(!popUpWindowAmountField.isEmpty()){
                    orderBasket=ordersService.getOrderWithStatusBasketByUser(loggedUser);
                    if(orderBasket==null){
                        List<Coffee>el=new ArrayList<>();
                        orderBasket=new Orders(loggedUser, el);
                    }
                    List<Coffee> list=orderBasket.getCoffees_in_orders();
                    for(int i=0; i<popUpWindowAmountField.getValue(); i++){
                        list.add(selectedCoffee);
                    }
                    orderBasket.setCoffees_in_orders(list);
                    //ordersService.addNewOrder(orderBasket);
                    ordersService.updateOrder(loggedUser,list);
                    //list.forEach(e-> System.out.println(e));
                    //orderBasket.getCoffees_in_orders().forEach(e-> System.out.println(e));
                    popUpWindow.close();
                }else{
                    popUpWindow.removeAll();
                    popUpWindow.add(new Text("Wybierz poprawną ilość!"));
                    popUpWindow.open();
                }
            }else{
                popUpWindow.removeAll();
                popUpWindow.add(new Text("Musisz się zalogować!"));
                popUpWindow.open();
            }
        });
```

I tried many many things.. I serached all web and couldn't find answer :(. I tried to change saving object to database (via service or od directly repository) as well, but no results. The exception points at this line:

```
ordersService.updateOrder(loggedUser,list);
```

This is fragment from service and repository, that is responsible for updating/ creating new item in database:
**Service:**

```
public void updateOrder(User user, List<Coffee> list){
        ordersRepository.updateOrders(user, list);
    }
```

**Repository:**

```
@Repository
public interface OrdersRepository extends JpaRepository<Orders,Integer> {
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("UPDATE Orders o SET o.coffees_in_orders = ?2 WHERE o.orderingUser = ?1")
    void updateOrders(User user, List<Coffee> list);
}
```